# Required cascading parameters in Blazor components

Tags: c#, blazor

```
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public int Parameter { get; set; } = default!;

[CascadingParameter, EditorRequired]
public int Parameter2 { get; set; } = default!;
```

The EditorRequired attribute emits RZ2012 only for regular parameters. Is there a way to get compile time warnings for cascading parameters if I do not set them?

Comment: Where would you expect that error?  When a Parent 'does not set it' then that is an app wide failure, hard to miss. If a Child does not receive it, where to put the attribute?

Comment: I'd put the attribute next to CascadingParameter like in the example and how it does work for Parameter. Then I would expect a warning like RZ2012 if the component is never wrapped with a <CascadingValue>. This would have to be checked app wide like you suggested. Yes, it is not 'hard to miss' but I would prefer a compile time check and not a runtime failure because a NullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't work with CascadingParameter.

Here's the AspNetCore team's code from `ValidationSummary` which needs the `EditContext` cascade.

```cs
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(ValidationSummary)} requires a cascading parameter " +
                $"of type {nameof(EditContext)}. For example, you can use {nameof(ValidationSummary)} inside " +
                $"an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
        }
```